# Obtaining the Standard Error of Weighted Data in SPSS

Tags: statistics, spss, s

I'm trying to find confidence intervals for the means of various variables in a database using SPSS, and I've run into a spot of trouble.

The data is weighted, because each of the people who was surveyed represents a different portion of the overall population. For example, one young man in our sample might represent 28000 young men in the general population. The problem is that SPSS seems to think that the young man's database entries each represent 28000 measurements when they actually just represent one, and this makes SPSS think we have much more data than we actually do. As a result SPSS is giving very very low standard error estimates and very very narrow confidence intervals.

I've tried fixing this by dividing every weight value by the mean weight. This gives plausible figures and an average weight of 1, but I'm not sure the resulting numbers are actually correct.

Is my approach sound? If not, what should I try?

I've been using the Explore command to find mean and standard error (among other things), in case it matters.

Comment: How do the weights arrive? Is it from a sample with unequal selection probabilities? (Or some other type of post-stratification?) For sample weights, you typically weight *inverse proportional* to the selection probabilities. I'm less familiar with post-stratification though.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure where the weights are from. I'll have to ask the people who gave me the database.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to scale weights to the actual sample size, but only the procedures in the Complex Samples option are designed to account for sampling weights properly.  The regular weight variable in Statistics is treated as a frequency weight.

Comment: That's discouraging. I don't have the Complex Samples option. I might have to use a different program. Anyway, thanks for letting me know.